# Swipe gesture randomly not recognized

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gesture

I'm using a basic gesture recognition script in my Air Android app. Sometimes the gesture is not recognized. It mostly happens if it's near the border of the screen or if the finger is moving too fast over the screen.

Is something wrong with my code or do I need to add additonal settings?

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe); 

function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
if (e.offsetY == 1) { 
 //User swiped towards bottom
showMenu()
 }
 else if (e.offsetY == -1) { 
 //User swiped towards top
hideMenu()
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like performance problem - your app is busy with calculating and keeping the frame rate, so it doesn't register the gesture in time ... Use something like [this](http://www.sociodox.com/theminer/) to find out the where and when the app slows down.

Comment: I don't think it's a performance problem because it's a seperate file only for the gesture testing purpose. There is nothing else in it.